I got emails stating I have.1.349230 BTC on the Binance Exchange. How do I find it if this is true?
I received emails stating I have 1.349230 currently sitting on the "Binance Exchange". (Payout amount: $138659.02)
To access funds in USD proceed to the cryptocurrency exchange.
How can I find this bitcoin and transfer it to my digital wallet?

Receiving unsolicited emails claiming you have significant funds on a crypto exchange like Binance is a common tactic used in phishing scams. Do Not Engage.
